# how can I save/update edited polyline in google map v3

Tags: google-maps, polyline

I am using google polyline to draw a road, so I make the polyline editable in order to make it more precise.
when I finished the editing, I want to  polyline.getPath() to get all the updated segment path, However the result is still the old polyline rather than the edited polyline. How can I do it?

more:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'capturing_changed', function(e) {
                       var path = this.getPath();
               console.log('capture event  '+path);
               for(i = 0; i < path.length; i++){
                            console.log("new point "+path.getAt(i));
                        }   
               console.log(e);

});
```

when I edit the polyline, I will get this event, using this event I can have a view of updated path, but this updated path misses many important dots. If I use the remaining dots on the updated path to build the poliline, this polyline is not the one I have edited before.

Apart from the capturing_changed event, when I edit the polyline, the set_at, insert_at, remove_at never fires to me

Comment: Please post your code that isn't working.  [Example of editing tool that exports updated polylines (among other things)](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html)